# .htaccess redirect directory to a single page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, web

I want to redirect **all** pages from the `.com/blog` directory to the `.com/error` directory.

I have searched the web, and found loads of different ways of doing it, but I want it to redirect to a **single** page.

All the things I have tried redirect to the same file name, but in different directory. For example, `.com/blog/index.nonexisting` redirects to `.com/error/index.nonexisting`.

I would like all files in the first directory to redirect to a certain file, so if you go to `.com/blog/whatever.php` it would go to `.com/error/index.php`, and if you go to `.com/blog/random.xml` you would be redirected to `.com/error/index.php`.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try putting this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+) error/index.php [L,R]
```

Replace `R` with `R=301` if you want a 301 redirect, and get rid of `R` entirely if you don't want an external redirect.

Comment: Friend I want to 301 redirect my total blog folder to home url. When someone point my blog link it automatically redirect to home page. Using htaccess. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks !! you save my much time

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress I used this for a subdmoain on a multisite.

So "subdomain.domain.org/wp_super_faq/AnyAndAllTextAtAll" will redirect to "subdomain.domain.org/faqs"

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp_super_faq.*$ https://subdomain\.domain\.org/faqs/ [R=301,L]
```