# .htaccess: Redirect user to specific page if he accesses directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm currently working on ironing out some little problems with my website and prep it for SEO a little bit. I followed Google's SEO Optimization guide and found this quote:

> Consider what happens when a user removes part of your URL - 
>   Some users might navigate your site in odd ways, and you should 
>   anticipate this. For example, instead of using the breadcrumb links 
>   on the page, a user might drop off a part of the URL in the hopes 
>   of finding more general content. He or she might be visiting `http://
>   www.brandonsbaseballcards.com/news/010/upcoming-baseballcard-shows.htm`, but
>   then enter `http://www.brandonsbaseballcards.com/news/010/` into 
>   the browser's address bar, believing that this will show all news from 
>   010. Is your site prepared to show content in this situation...?

Well, currently my site is not prepared for this situation and would direct the user to a directory or a 404 page.

I searched on the web for a little bit and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656103/htaccess-https-redirection-virtual-folder-access-with-exceptions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642602/htacess-redirect-directory-to-a-single-page) link which seem to go into the right direction but I wasn't quite sure. Ideally, I would like to try this out on localhost (XAMPP) before I upload the page.

So my question would be, how would I redirect (through htaccess) a user who puts in, say, `http://www.example.com/baseballcards` to `http://www.example/baseballcards/all.html`?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(baseballcards)/?$ /$1/all.html [L,NC]
```

Above rule will internally forward `/baseballcards` to `/baseballcards/all.html` but won't change the URL in the browser (external redirect). If you want external redirection then use following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(baseballcards)/?$ /$1/all.html [R=301,L,NC]
```